# Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't recognize raid array on Lenovo P71

Tags: server, partitioning, hard-drive, raid, mdadm

We have a Lenovo P71 with Ubuntu 18.04 (not server edition) installed. We recently installed 2 M.2 SSD modules and set up the bios for them to be a raid 1 array (mother board built-in intel hardware raid 1). Ubuntu doesn't recognize the array and we can't seem to find an answer on-line. So, did we waste our money on this addition or is there a solution? We want to clone the existing hard drive to the array and then use the hard drive for other stuff. Thanks in advance!!

08/01/2019

Is there anyone out there that has a clue on this subject/problem?

Comment: Do you have to use the builtin RAID (e.g. are you running a dual boot), or would software raid with mdadm work? Generally [fakeraid](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto) doesn't give improved performance over softwareraid anyway.

Comment: @vidarlo That's not a comment!  That's an answer!  Please post one and ping me and user68186 and we'll come back and upvote!  **;-)**

Comment: What we would like to do is, to boot linux from the array (no dual boot involved - we run windows under VM) and therefore have our system and it's data mirrored. It appears that "fakeraid ?" would allow that functionality but don't know if software raid would. Our P71 has enough power to handle either method, so we have no preference.

Comment: @vidarlo It looks like software raid is better supported and more efficient. I have no experience with either. Those who know these things should answer.